# Why does Rcout and Rprintf cause stack limit error when multithreading?

Tags: c++, r, multithreading, rcpp

So in the following code I am using `std::thread()` to report program progress, the example has been altered to report at an unreasonable interval with an uninformative message in order to demonstrate the issue.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
using namespace Rcpp;

void reporter(const std::atomic<bool> &running) {
    while (running) {
        Rprintf( "Program running...\n" );
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(10));
    }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void example() {
    int i = 1;
    std::atomic<bool> running{true};

    std::thread reporter_thread(
        [&] () { reporter(running); }
    );

    while (true) {
        i++;
        i--;
    }


    return;
}
```

On my 2017 MacBook Pro this triggers a `stack usage is too close to the limit` crash at exactly the 93rd print. This also crashes if I change to `Rprintf`, however as far as I can tell `std::cout` is immune.

I can change the code such that the printing happens in the parent thread with a flag that gets toggled in the spawned thread which also appears to evade the crash.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
using namespace Rcpp;

void reporter(const std::atomic<bool> &running, std::atomic<bool> &print_message) {
    while (running) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(10));
        print_message = true;
    }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void example() {
    int i = 1;
    std::atomic<bool> running{true};
    std::atomic<bool> print_message{true};

    std::thread reporter_thread(
        [&] () { reporter(running, print_message); }
    );

    while (true) {
        i++;
        i--;
        if (print_message)
            Rprintf( "Program running...\n" );
            print_message = false;
    }


    return;
}
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why does the first version cause the crash.
2. Is the second version guaranteed to be safe?

Comment: If you want to publish on CRAN where std::cout is not allowed, you could consider guarding your Rcout << in a simple mutex like spin_mutex, although this could have a speed penalty depending on how frequently your threads fight for output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your first example [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support) has to say:

> Calling any of the R API from threaded code is ‘for experts only’: they will need to read the source code to determine if it is thread-safe. In particular, code which makes use of the stack-checking mechanism must not be called from threaded code.

I would stay away from calling R API functions in threaded code. I am not sure about you second example, but would look for existing solutions first, e.g. http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-rcppprogress/.